# Classifier Name

Tags: python, pandas, gridsearchcv

I got a hyperparameter tuning and the best model.
I created a dataframe that contains best_model.cv_results_.

I wanted to extract the best mean accuracy of each classifier but I'm running into a small problem.

```
pipe = Pipeline([("scaler", StandardScaler()),
                ("classifier", RandomForestClassifier())])

grid_param = [
    {"classifier": [RandomForestClassifier(random_state=17)],
    "classifier__n_estimators": [50,100,200],
    "classifier__criterion":["gini", "entropy"],
    "classifier__max_features": ['auto','sqrt','log2'],
    "classifier__max_depth": [4,5,6,7,8,9]
    },
    {"classifier": [LogisticRegression(random_state=17)],
    "classifier__penalty": ["l2"],
    "classifier__C": np.logspace(-1, 4, 8),
    "classifier__solver":["newton-cg", "saga", "sag", "liblinear"],
    "classifier__max_iter": [10, 100, 1000]
    },
    {"classifier": [SVC(random_state=17)],
    "classifier__kernel": ["linear","rbf","sigmoid"],
    "classifier__max_iter": np.logspace(0,3,4),
    "classifier__C": np.logspace(-1,4,6),
    "classifier__gamma": ['scale','auto']
    }
]


gridsearch = GridSearchCV(pipe, grid_param, cv = 5, verbose = 0, n_jobs = -1)
best_model = gridsearch.fit(x_tune, y_tune['quart_binary'])
df = pd.DataFrame(best_model.cv_results_)
```

I tried to extract by using str.contains like below:

```
df[df["params"].str.contains("RandomForestClassifier")]
df[df["params"].str.contains("LogisticRegression")]
df[df["params"].str.contains("SVC")]
```

And I'm getting this error below:

> KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan,\n              ...\n              nan, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],\n             dtype='float64',
> length=348)] are in the [columns]"

If I set contains na=False I get no results. I tried case and regex as well.
I think it has to do with the type of params.

```
0      {'classifier': RandomForestClassifier(criterio...
1      {'classifier': RandomForestClassifier(criterio...
2      {'classifier': RandomForestClassifier(criterio...
3      {'classifier': RandomForestClassifier(criterio...
4      {'classifier': RandomForestClassifier(criterio...
                             ...                        
343    {'classifier': SVC(random_state=17), 'classifi...
344    {'classifier': SVC(random_state=17), 'classifi...
345    {'classifier': SVC(random_state=17), 'classifi...
346    {'classifier': SVC(random_state=17), 'classifi...
347    {'classifier': SVC(random_state=17), 'classifi...
Name: params, Length: 348, dtype: object
```

If anyone could help me or give an advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the class name of the classifier:

```
df['classifier'] = pd.json_normalize(df['params'])['classifier'] \
                     .map(lambda x: x.__class__.__name__)
```

Output:

```
>>> df[['param_classifier', 'classifier']]
                                         param_classifier              classifier
0    RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=4, random_state=17)  RandomForestClassifier
1    RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=4, random_state=17)  RandomForestClassifier
2    RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=4, random_state=17)  RandomForestClassifier
3    RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=4, random_state=17)  RandomForestClassifier
4    RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=4, random_state=17)  RandomForestClassifier
..                                                    ...                     ...
343                                  SVC(random_state=17)                     SVC
344                                  SVC(random_state=17)                     SVC
345                                  SVC(random_state=17)                     SVC
346                                  SVC(random_state=17)                     SVC
347                                  SVC(random_state=17)                     SVC

[348 rows x 2 columns]
```

Usage:

```
>>> df[df['classifier'] == 'LogisticRegression']
     mean_fit_time  std_fit_time  mean_score_time  std_score_time  ... mean_test_score std_test_score rank_test_score          classifier
108       0.007038      0.000404         0.000549        0.000007  ...            0.88        0.04000             118  LogisticRegression
109       0.004858      0.002748         0.000593        0.000059  ...            0.88        0.04000             118  LogisticRegression
110       0.002688      0.000180         0.000586        0.000055  ...            0.88        0.04000             118  LogisticRegression
111       0.002499      0.001054         0.000574        0.000045  ...            0.89        0.02000             111  LogisticRegression
112       0.006591      0.001276         0.000515        0.000090  ...            0.88        0.04000             118  LogisticRegression
..             ...           ...              ...             ...  ...             ...            ...             ...                 ...
199       0.001976      0.000267         0.000433        0.000091  ...            0.82        0.04000             237  LogisticRegression
200       0.014224      0.000657         0.000540        0.000034  ...            0.82        0.04000             237  LogisticRegression
201       0.026070      0.004995         0.000519        0.000108  ...            0.81        0.04899             259  LogisticRegression
202       0.023317      0.004925         0.000544        0.000117  ...            0.81        0.04899             259  LogisticRegression
203       0.002114      0.000404         0.000522        0.000103  ...            0.82        0.04000             237  LogisticRegression

[96 rows x 25 columns]
```